# Finding a commutative ring $A$ without $1$, and a nonzero element $f$ such that $f$ is inside every prime ideal.

Tags: abstract-algebra

**Question:** Given a commutative ring A.

Let $r\in A$ and if $r\in p$ for every proper prime ideal $p\subset A$ can we conclude that $r=0$.

If $A$ was integral domain then $(0)$ would be prime ideal so $r$ would be inside of intersection of every prime ideal then $r=0$.

However if $A$ was not integral domain I believe I can find some counter example.

Comment: "If $A$ were an integral domain" then $A$ would not be a "commutative ring without $1$". Integral domains, **by definition**, have a $1\neq 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $R=\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$, $S=2\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$, and let $A=R\times S$. Since $S$ does not have a $1$, neither does $A$.

Let $I$ be an ideal of $A$. If $(a,b)\in I$, then $(a,0)\in I$ (multiplying by $(\overline{1},\overline{0})$), hence $(a,b)-(a,0)=(0,b)\in I$. Thus, every ideal of $A$ is of the form $J_1\times J_2$, with $J_1$ an ideal of $R$, and $J_2$ and ideal of $S$.

So there are six ideals of $A$ (since $R$ has three ideals and $S$ has two). But an ideal of the form $J_1\times\{\overline{0}\}$ is not prime, since $(\overline{0},\overline{2})^2\in J_1\times\{\overline{0}\}$. So the only possible prime ideals are $\{\overline{0}\}\times S$ and $(2\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z})\times S$.

The first is not prime, since $(\overline{2},\overline{0})^2\in \{\overline{0}\}\times S$, but the first component of the element is nonzero.

Now, if $(x,y)(z,w) = (xz,yw)\in (2\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z})\times S$, then $xy\in 2\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$, hence either $x\in 2\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$ or $y\in 2\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$. Either way, one of the two factors lies in $(2\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z})\times S$. Thus, this is a prime ideal, and is in fact the *only* prime ideal of $A$.

In particular, $(\overline{2},\overline{0})$ and $(\overline{2},\overline{2})$ are nonzero elements which lie in every prime ideal of $A$.